# Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc3

Tags: android, android-studio

> Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc3
>
> Install Build Tools 23.0.0 rc3 and sync project.
>   Warning: The package
>   filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
>            Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

[image]

Answer (score 38):

Solution:
**A) Module Settings GUI**

1) Go to Module Settings -> Press F4
2) Select "app" under Modules
3) Select the "Properties" tab
4) Check the Build Tools Version values.
5) See if you find the value "23.0.0rc3"
6) If not go to select the maximum possible value such as "23.0.0"

[image: Project Settings]

**B) "gradle.build" update**

In this change the `buildToolsVersion` value in the `build.gradle` file of **app** module from `buildToolsVersion '23.0.0rc3'` to `buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'`

I hope that helps.
Happy Coding...

Comment: Mr Devendra Vaja i have followed your steps but the problem is not resolved, do you have any other idea to resolve this issue. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Please let me know the nature of error and error log. I will try my best to resolve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Hi,I'm newbie to Android Studio, I was imported the material design sample program from google on that moment android shows this error.

Comment: Pls share the version of the "Build Tools Version" (refer the image above)

Answer (score 8):

Try deleting  rc3 from your buildToolsVersion

So you'll have this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
}
```

and not this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Install the Build Tools in the SDK Manager

Answer (score 3):

Update your sdk with latest version of android API level 23 and update following line like....

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

As ***Devendra Vaja*** said but at least, in my Android Studio version 3.0.1, I could access to this option on the following way:

[image]

[image]

I hope it helps.