# Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc1

Tags: android

As of today I've been running into an error setting up new projects in Android Studio.  Right after creating a blank project the log mentions "Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc1."

First I looked online to see how to resolve this and came across [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111579/errorfailed-to-find-build-tools-revision-23-0-0-rc3), and followed the solution given (setting the build tools version in the module settings).  However, this results in Android Studio telling me that the method "android()" cannot be found and "The project 'TestBlankApplication' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method."

Additionally, the SDK Manager informs me that I have Build-tools 24 rc1 installed.  So I do not know why Android Studio cannot find it.

[Screencap of SDK Manager showing 24 rc1 installed:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu8WH.jpg)
[image]

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?  Thank you.

Comment: Try installing the "Android SDK Tools" in the "Tools (Preview Channel)" area of the SDK Manager.

Comment: Just tried it -- the error persists.  I will try updating Android Studio.  If that doesn't help I may end up reinstalling it.

Comment: If you look in your Android SDK directory (the one shown at the top of the SDK Manager), in the `build-tools/` subdirectory, do you see a `24.0.0-preview/` directory? Usually, these directory names line up with what you put in `buildToolsVersion` in `build.gradle`, but for whatever reason, `'24.0.0 rc1'` turns into `24.0.0-preview/` in the SDK.

Comment: I switched the name of the `24.0.0-preview` directory to `24.0.0 rc1` and that resolved the errors above.  It also introduced a new error for the Gradle sync: `Gradle sync failed: Could not build 'org.gradle.tooling.model.gradle.GradleBuild' model. Build cancelled.`

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean for you to rename the directory. On my machine, the directory is `24.0.0-preview/`, but the Gradle build script is `'24.0.0 rc1'`. I was wondering if you were just missing the directory outright, due to a failed SDK update or something.

Comment: I ended up removing Android Studio and all associated content and tried a fresh install.  So far it seems to be working OK.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: You must specify `gradle-2.11-all.zip` in your **gradle-wrapper.properties**

Comment: Post your gradle files. Both project and module

Answer (score 178):

## Why you got this error:

Android studio does not come with build tools for different android versions when you download it. It also does not make sense since there are multiple versions of build tools and each of them will take hundreds of megabytes on your hard drive. This is why Android Studio installation package is 1 GB while Xcode, which has all the build tools, is 6 GB

When you choose a specific build version in the build.gradle file, your android studio may or may not have that version of build tool installed. And if not, you will see the error complaining about it.

## How to fix it

You just need to install the specific version of build tool mentioned in build.gradle like this:

1. Click ***File*** > ***Settings*** (on a Mac, ***Android Studio*** > ***Preferences***) to
   open the Settings dialog.
2. Go to ***Appearance & Behavior*** > ***System Settings*** > ***Android SDK*** (Or
   simply search for ***Android SDK*** on the search bar)
3. Go to ***SDK Tools*** tab > Check the ***Show Package Details*** check box
4. Select the specific version of the build tool and click on the ***Apply***
   button
5. After the installation, sync the project

## Demos

(I choose a different version just to show you how to apply the changes by that apply button :) )

[image]

And then sync the project. The error is gone now!

[image]

Comment: Newbie here, this really is a stupid question on my side, but I thought the latest android versions include previous versions. i.e. I had API level 26 installed but my error came from the build wanting API level 24. I thought having the latest version avoids this?

Comment: @DeanP Negative. As I explained above, each version has to be downloaded & used separately and they are different than each other. Newer versions may have some new features & element while some of them could also be removed. IIRC, the tab view is added in recent build tool and its not available in previous ones

Comment: The screen capture was masterful! +10

Comment: For our problem was due to not using single quotes for dependencies external gradle.

`"24.0.1"` into `'24.0.1'`

Comment: Why the _Build tools_ settings are not in the _Build_ menu or the _Tools_ menu is beyond me.  Why it's not under _Settings > Tools_ is beyond me.  Why it's not under _Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment_ is beyond me.  Why it's **actually** under _Settings > Appearance & Behavior_ is just so strange, I can't even...

Answer (score 16):

Try to change the buildToolsVersion for 23.0.2
in Gradle Script build.gradle (Module App)

and set buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

then rebuild

Answer (score 12):

1. Follow the below procedure to solve the error.
2. Go to File -> Project structure.

[image]

1. From the drop down box, you will know all the version of build tools that are installed in your android studio.
2. Look for a higher version. If Gradle cannot find 24.0.0, check if 24.0.1 is present in drop down.
3. Do a complete code search. Find all the places where "24.0.0" is found. Replace it with "24.0.1"
4. Do a gradle sync.

Comment: Perfect solution!!

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem and eventually found out that in file build.gradle the version does not match the version of buildTools in my installed sdk.
(because I imported project done at home on different computed with updated sdk)

**before:**

- build.gradle(app): buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
- Android\sdk\build-tools: file "25.0.1"

**fixed:**
build.gradle(app): buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

Then just sync your project with gradle files and it should work.

Comment: Got it to work this; quite simply. Thanks. (Even though mine was 24.0.0 and 23.0.0, still worked)

Comment: if you are looking for `build.gradle(app)` it is in your `app` folder. Usually if Android studio fails on running gradle it fails to add the virtual node for `build.gradle(app)` to the project tree view.

Answer (score 4):

SDK tools required build tool version installation helped me.
You just need to install required build tool version from,

SDK Manager -> SDK tool -> Show Package details -> Select required build tool version and install it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Build Gradle (Module:app)
Change the following.
In my case, I choose 25.0.3

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cesarhcq.viisolutions"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
```

After that, it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio updating didn't work for me. So I updated it manually. Go to your sdk location, run SDK Manager, mark desired build tools version and install.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem after a fresh install of Android Studio (in GNU/Linux). I also used the installation wizard for Android SDK, and the Build Tools 28.0.3 were installed, although Android Studio tried to use 28.0.2 instead.

But the problem was not the build tools version but the license. I had not accepted the Android SDK license (the wizard does not ask for it), and Android Studio refused to use the build tools; the error message just is wrong.

In order to solve the problem, I manually accepted the license. In a terminal, I launched `$ANDROID_SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` and answered "Yes" for the SDK license. The other ones can be refused.

Comment: Works! This is something unusual I found while working with Android for last 8 years.

Answer (score 1):

faced the same problem: Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision x.x.x

**reason:** the build tools for that version was not down loaded properly
**solution:**

1. Click File > Settings (on a Mac, Android Studio > Preferences) to open the Settings dialog.
2. Go to Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK (Or simply search for Android SDK on the search bar)
3. Go to SDK Tools tab > Check the Show Package Details checkbox
4. uncheck the specific version to remove it.
5. click apply.

then follow the steps 1 to 3 and 6.

6. Select the specific version of the build tool and click on the Apply button
   After the installation, sync the project

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is that all libraries from google (e.g. support lib, `CardView` and etc.) should have identical versions

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a same problem.
I was running portable version of android studio so downloaded a package from https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads
and installed it, and like that, done!

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to change to version that is available on you studio 
[image]

2) Here is how you find out version that is available for your studio

Go to File -> Project structure.
[image]

source is from @Siddarth Kanted Thanks to Siddarth Kanted.

3) And when you want to install more versions of build tool you can learn it from @Fangming user from this post.

easy working solution.

Comment: Is there something missing between steps 2 and 3? I don't see a "Properties" tab.