# Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.0.2 but they are installed

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the error "Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.0.2" but when I go to android SDK manager, over to SDK Tools, check 'show package details', under Android SDK Build-Tools, it shows 25.0.2 as installed.

It is installed in {USER}/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/

I'm running Android Studio 2.3.3. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed by invalidating cache & restarting (in file menu)

Comment: If this action helped you resolve your issue then please consider marking this answer as accepted. You can use the grey check mark below voting buttons to do so. It helps the community to focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2):

In file build.gradle you have to change the line:

buildToolsVersion:{version} **to**
buildToolsVersion:25.0.2

as pointed out here: 
[Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019599/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-24-0-0-rc1)

Comment: buildToolsVersion was already correct, my problem was i had to invalidate the cache & restart

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that google maven is added to your project `build.gradle`:

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    name 'Google'
}
```

and `buildToolsVersion:25.0.2` is updated to `25.0.3` (or newer)