# In Android studio, I'm getting an error that says "Packages unavailable" and that a package I need is not available

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio,

I'm getting an error about building my app.

```
Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.1.0
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 26.1.0 and sync project</a>
```

This results in a blue install link, but when I click it I get an error telling me that, "Package Unavailable" and that "Packages are unavailable."

Here's what my build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.leoconnelly.connexus"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    buildToolsVersion '26.1.0'

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

//Helpshift
// use version 26.1.0 instead of 26.0.2
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

implementation('com.helpshift:android-helpshift-en-aar:6.4.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview'
    exclude module: 'cardview-v7'

}


}
```

How do I resolve this issue? I've tried messing wth my SDK manager already. All the solutions I've found insofar do not work.

EDIT: I tried installing 26.0.1 on an a brand new project and I had the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019599/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-24-0-0-rc1)

Answer (score -1):

You just have to move to SDK Platform 8.0.

It won't change things for you regarding target and min api, and the apps will still work on older Android version.

Just download this file and extract it.

> https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r26.0.2-windows.zip

copy all files from [android-8.1.0] and move them into

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1
```

Comment: Hello! I actually found this exact question before and it didn't work :(

Comment: @SamWilson Okay! No issues. I will look for another solution and get back to you.

Comment: @SamWilson just download this file and extract it. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r26.0.2-windows.zip copy all files from [android-8.1.0] and move them into  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1

Comment: I'm on mac, does that change where I go?

Comment: @SamWilson That I'm not sure about. Sorry. Can't help with that.

Comment: @SamWilson Can you please mark it as correct if I was able to help you?

Comment: So I checked in the terminal and I found that the folder contains 26.0.1

Comment: @SamWilson That's great. Let me know if the solution works fine for you.

Comment: It does not. This is a bit strange. I'm  not really sure what to do.