# Can't find Android Build Tools 26.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Earlier today I posted a question about how I couldn't get my Android app to run. Here is the error:

```
Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.1.0
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 26.1.0 and sync project</a>
```

I tried this trick [Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019599/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-24-0-0-rc1), and it didn't work but I realized that on Android studio I was installing 26.0.1 which I was confusing with 26.1.0. Does anyone know how to get that version?

Check out my original question here: 
[In Android studio, I'm getting an error that says "Packages unavailable" and that a package I need is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904786/in-android-studio-im-getting-an-error-that-says-packages-unavailable-and-tha/49904891?noredirect=1#comment86829069_49904891)

Here is my build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.leoconnelly.connexus"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    buildToolsVersion '26.1.0'
    //buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

//Helpshift
// use version 26.1.0 instead of 26.0.2
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

implementation('com.helpshift:android-helpshift-en-aar:6.4.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview'
    exclude module: 'cardview-v7'

}


}
```

I'm also on Mac.

Comment: share your **`build.Gradle`** with question

Comment: up sorry completely forgot to add it

Comment: I fixed it!!!!!

Comment: @SamWilson Please post the solution then

Answer (score 2):

Change the number 26.0.1 i think there is not 26.1.0 build tool version see this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html) and you have added two times buildToolsVersion in your Build.Gradle file.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html