# android studio Gradle sync failed: Failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm a complete beginner with android studio and I downloaded and installed the IDE earlier today. I started following this course which they recommend you start with. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project . Once I added an empty activity to the project i got an error saying Gradle Project Sync failed. I then pressed the sync project with gradle files button and it did some stuff then came back with this error: Gradle sync failed: Failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.2. I haven't installed anything else yet and I'm wondering what i did wrong? Can anyone help?

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47086581/1008011)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019599/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-24-0-0-rc1)

Comment: Thanks guys, that one solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to build.gradle(Module: app) and check compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion, if it's 28 change to 26 or less.
if you wanna to use API 28 you must download build tools revision 28.0.2