# update android Build Tools revision to 28.0.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated the android stadio to version '3.2.1' and the android stadio asked me to update something like `tools.build:gradle` to `3.2.1` and i did, 
Now the gradle version is 4.6 and it says `Failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.3`.
 i tried to install it but some error occur that informed 'the packages are not available for download'. 
 what the hell wrong with it? wish i never updated it

Comment: Maybe it'll help https://stackoverflow.com/a/47086581/4773117

Comment: 28.0.3 is not exist in the list of SDK manager update

Comment: Anybody knows how to overcome this problem ?

Comment: paste gradle code here. also degrade libraries to 28.0.2 and navigate to platformtools in android directory and remove 28.0.3 folder if there is any

Answer (score 3):

Read [**`Build Tools, Revision 28.0.3 (September 2018)`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools)

> You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by
>   downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager. If
>   you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project
>   automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the
>   plugin specifies.

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    ...
}
```

Your **`gradle-wrapper.properties`** will

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

Your **`build.gradle`** <kbd>**classpath**</kbd> will

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha12'
    }
```

**FYI**

It will be better if you use

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    ...
}
```

Finally, **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart IDE`**

Comment: gradle-4.10.2 just has helped me. (it was 4.10.0 before)

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck with the same problem. After digging in code's log it says sdk doesn't have permission or that it was readable only. So I open Android Studio in administrator mode(right click on the icon-> run as administrator) and then I could install build Tools revision. This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and fixed it this way:

1. Find the sdk-manager path and run it directly. (Without android
   studio!)
2. Accept the therms.
3. Use android studio and gradle normally.