# Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 23.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

**Error: failed to find Build Tools revision 23.3.0**
Install Build Tools 23.3.0 and sync project

Comment: Use the link below to solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32149946/5575289

and android studio will download what it needs at startup. Maybe you should use a vpn to get the needed tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to import new Gradle project: failed to find Build Tools revision \*.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619773/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

The build tools should be `23.0.3 and not 23.3.0` 
in build.gradle file change the

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```